# <uses-feature> tag for AirGesture on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, gesture, samsung-mobile

I am making an app which should only be installed on devices having the samsung airgesture capability. If the app were to be published on the play store that is very easy i can just select those devices, but it will not be published. So I thought of using the `< use-feature >` tag in the manifest so that the APK would not install if your phone does not have this feature. I could not find the identification of this feature to put that in the manifest. Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i don't think that is possible. I checked the list of supported values for those tags and there is nothing related to this. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features.

The fallback will be to have the app installed, but just display a message when the Device.model does not match the expected one

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Play - Developer Console, you can specify on which devices you do not want your app installed.

This means, you have to know the devices with airgesture.